# What is a good Android-compatible Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth

I have a Galaxy Note 4, and sometimes it's nice to be able to do proper typing on it, and saving having to carry a laptop around.

I'd like a Bluetooth keyboard I can carry with me (doesn't have to fit in my pocket, it can stay in my bag).

Requirements:

- Responsive keyboard. I.e. soft keys aren't going to suit.
- Full/large sized. I have large hands, and I need to be able to touch type.
- That said, as small as possible. A standard desktop keyboard sized keyboard isn't going to suit.
- Numpad, F-keys etc, aren't needed. Just letters, number row, shift, space and enter.

Answer (score 8):

The **Anker® Bluetooth Ultra-Slim Keyboard** is a very small, cheap, and light Bluetooth keyboard, and it seems to be a good fit for your needs. It has full sized keys, and retails for 16.00. It also comes in both black and white. You can buy one [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0096M8VR2).

Another slightly more expensive option is the **Jelly Comb Universal Back-lit keyboard**. It retails for 20$, has all the same features as the Anker® keyboard, and is backlit. Coincidentally, this keyboard also comes in both white and black. You can buy one [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NG8EJOG).

Answer (score 3):

[iClever](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YWLJNPQ) keyboard seems to fit your requirements.

Number row is included. To use with Android you just have to choose <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

It is lightweight (0.39lbs =~ 176.9 grams) and tri-folding which makes it perfect for travel (size: 145mm x 95mm x 15mm).

To sum up:

- compact size
- keyboard spacing is not cramped
- aluminum body
- rubber feet on the bottom (for anti-skid)
- bluetooth range: 10 meters
- iOS, Windows and Android compatibility

Cons:

- size & placement of the backspace button (mentioned in the second review linked below).

Check the review [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gS37D4YR4JY) and [here](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1CUB673YFPK9P/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00YWLJNPQ&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=541966&store=pc):

> I have a few bluetooth keyboards and the iClever Tri-folding Magnetic
>   keyboard is the best for travel. It is the smallest and most compact
>   keyboard I've seen while maintaining a standard keyboard layout
>   (roughly an 11" laptop). The backspace key is too small for my
>   preference so that will take some getting used to. Other than that,
>   this keyboard is everything I want when I travel. The keyboard spacing
>   is not too cramped. It is only an inch less in length compared to my
>   13" laptop (my main laptop). The keyboard unfolds easily and only when
>   you want it to. Due to the magnets and hinge design, it won't happen
>   on accident. It tucks into itself so it is very easy to pack for
>   travel. The keys themselve have good feedback. There are many shortcut
>   keys that are activated with the typical Fn key (which is full size
>   and appropriately placed, thank goodness). There are no external
>   switches or keys to turn the keyboard on/off or enable sync (which is
>   a great thing. You hit the Fn key and letter C for BT sync shortcut).
>   As soon as you unfold the keyboard, it will turn on and connect to the
>   paired device. My devices found the keyboard immediately and connected
>   reliable throughout my testing.

Comment: Instead of linking to reviews, try to quote them in your answer to support your argument for why this product is better.

Comment: It is a simple product and the review is posted as a video. I will edit my answer to add part of another review.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a price range (and its a little pricy) but the [microsoft universa1 foldable](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Microsoft-Universal-Foldable-Keyboard/productID.315201200) keyboard meets many of your requirements.

[image]

- Responsive keyboard. I.e. soft keys aren't going to suit.

Its chicklet style, and the same sort of switches as the MS surface typing keyboard. Tested has a [mini review](http://www.tested.com/tech/547374-show-and-tell-microsoft-universal-folding-keyboard/) that suggests it has a decent amount of travel

- Full/large sized. I have large hands, and I need to be able to touch type.
  80% full sized keys, though there's a split inbetween
- That said, as small as possible. A standard desktop keyboard sized keyboard isn't going to suit.

Its flat but wide. It should fold up to a pretty small size

- Numpad, F-keys etc, aren't needed. Just letters, number row, shift, space and enter.

Yup 10keyless

Additional neat stuff?

- It can pair with more than one device, and is compatible with the big 2 phone OSes, and windows and OS X. Not sure if its linux compatible
- water resistant
- BT 4.0 based so you wouldn't need another dongle with many modern devices.

  RRP is ~99usd, tho you might be able to get it for ~70 usd according to tested.

Comment: That is cool. It folds! Would it be hard to type with that break in the middle?

Comment: It really depends. I suspect it would be a small learning curve, but its about the only way to do it. The *other* keyboard I was thinking of is vaporware

Comment: The OP said that he could fit it in his backpack... So it doesn't need to be tiny, although I can't help but admit that foldable keyboards are awesome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really cool product. Projects a laser keyboard and uses infrared to detect where your fingers are. You could actually fit it in your pocket. Only problem is the price, $90, which may be slightly over your price range.

You can [buy it here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008D6IUG4).

[image]